# Understanding the increment in the array (v6++)[4] = v9;

Tags: c

I have decompiled some .elf file with IDA's hex rays, what it gave me:

```
signed int __fastcall SEC_calc_(unsigned int a1, unsigned int a2, _DWORD *a3)
{
  char v30;    
  v3 = a1;
  v4 = a2;
  v6 = &v30;
  int v7;
  unsigned int v9;
  unsigned int v8; 
  v7 = 0;
  do
  {
    v8 = v4 >> v7;
    v9 = v3 >> v7;
    v7 += 8;
    *v6 = v8;
    (v6++)[4] = v9;
  }
  while ( v7 != 32 );
```

Assume that

```
 a1 = 0xC9A6010C
 a2 = 0xF1FFDFEF
```

I can understand that it's shifting the bits to the right and increasing the shifting value by 8 every loop until v7=32 (means only 4 loops). But what is

```
*v6 = v8;
(v6++)[4] = v9;
```

*v6 = v8 is pointer right? so t means v30 will equal v8 value as well?
and I completely don't understand

```
 (v6++)[4] = v9;
```

why its an increment in the [4] array? And why it is signed with v9?

Comment: @Yunnosch. If someone wrote that by hand, they would likely not maintain a job for long :) Also, the first sentence indicates it to be so.

Comment: I highly suspect that the decompiled code isn't entirely correct, as compiling is an irresponsible process.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Blind me... and caught by you. I had to restrain myself to not rant about readability. No brain power left for careful reading of prose... My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> *v6 = v8;
> (v6++)[4] = v9;
> ```
>
> *v6 = v8 is pointer right? so t means v30 will equal v8 value as well?

`v6` is the pointer, so `*v6` designates the object it points to (`v30` in this case).  Thus, yes, `*v6 = v8` copies the current value of variable `v8` to variable `v30`.

> I completely don't understand
>
> ```
>  (v6++)[4] = v9;
> ```
>
> why its an increment in the [4] array?

`v6++` evaluates to the current value of `v6`, with a side effect of afterward incrementing `v6` by one.  The overall statement is approximately equivalent to these two separate statements:

```
 v6[4] = v9;
 v6 = v6 + 1;
```

For its part, `v6[4]` designates the object of the same type as `*v6` that appears four positions after `*v6`, just as if `v6` itself designated an array having at least five elements.

> And why it is signed with v9?

The `= v9` part is a straightforward assignment.  It assigns the current value of variable `v9` to the object designated by `(v6++)[4]`.  I would have to study the code a lot more deeply to hypothesize about why the function performs that assignment.

Comment: It's filling in the two 4 byte values following v30 in the stack.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, it is assigning *four* values the size of `v6`'s type (which is not necessarily four bytes even if that type is `int`), starting  four positions past `v30`.  But that's *what*, not *why*.

Comment: It's 4 bytes because v7 is the loop variable and char is guaranteed to be 1 byte. It actually looks like it might be swapping v3 as well as dividing them by 256. Still no idea why of course

Comment: so it means that for example, v9 for the first loop after shifting will be the same "C9A6010C" after the second loop of shifting it will be "A6010C00", then "010C0000" , "0C000000" and stay the same on the 32bit shifting, and it stores by the 1 shifted value in the array, 5 int array elements, right? so it will be "C9A6010C" in the v6[0], "A6010C00" in the v6[1], am i right? also v6++ increment does it incrementing &v30 value? or from the zero?

Comment: @JohnWick, to "increment" means to add to the current value.  In particular the `++` operator adds 1 to the current value.  Note well that it is the pointer (an address) that is being incremented, not the value of the object to which it points.  The precise details of what happens for specific inputs and outputs depends to some extent on data that have not been captured by the decompiler, or at least that are not presented in the question.  These include data types and memory layouts.

Comment: @JohnBollinger last two questions please before I accept your answer, "object designated by (v6++)[4]" - does it mean that it creates 4 more addresses where it stores the value of v9 in each of them, after the v6 variable address? i didn't write the " memset(&v30, 0, 0x10u)" in my questions, but it is before the do-while loop, doesn't it mean it clears the 10 address after v30 address with zeros right? i think it is doing it in order to store values from v6[4] = v9; v6 = v6 + 1;

Comment: @JohnWick, the answer already addresses `(v6++)[4]` in some detail.  It does not create any addresses.  It *refers* to a single object, not four, exactly as if the sub-expression `v6++` evaluated to an array rather than to a pointer.  The `[4]` is the ordinary indexing operator, with index 4.  The `memset()` call you now describe writes the value 0 to each of 16 (0x10) consecutive bytes, starting with `v30`.  This suggests that v30 in the decompiled source corresponds to an object declared as an array in the original source.

Answer (score 1):

`(v6++)[4] = v9;` is a nasty bit of code that you hopefully don't write by hand like that.

First, break out the post increment:

```
v6[4] = v9;
v6++;
```

`v6` is a `char *`, which means that it can be indexed, dereferenced, and incremented. You are assigning the lowest byte of integer `v9` to the 5th element of `v6`, which is 4, then 5, then 6 and finally 7 characters past the location of `v30`. After the assignment, move `v6` up one byte.

By the way, the previous line, `*v6 = v8;` assigns to `v30`, then the next byte and the next and the next. The loop iterates 4 times, since you check when `v7 == 32` in increments of 8. That means that the two assignments are relying on `v3` and `v4` immediately following `v30` on the stack and writing to those bytes.

That last assumption may be undefined behavior, but I am not a language lawyer.

Comment: so it means that for example, v9 for the first loop after shifting will be the same "C9A6010C" after the second loop of shifting it will be "A6010C00", then "010C0000" , "0C000000" and stay the same on the 32bit shifting, and it stores by the 1 shifted value in the array,  5 int array elements, right? so it will be "C9A6010C" in the v6[0], "A6010C00" in the v6[1], am i right? also v6++ increment does it incrementing &v30 value? or from the zero?

Comment: v6 increments the value (address) of the pointer by the size of one element, which is 1 byte because char is always 1 byte and v6 is declared as a char*. When you assign to the pointer, you assign one byte, even when the rhs is an int.

Comment: why did you say that it's 7 characters past the location of v30, if it's only [4] - which is 5 characters? Sorry if I don't understand something